# Crawling a website using Laravel & Elvedia\Goutte: How to extract JSON

Tags: php, json, goutte

I managed to access succesfully a remote JSON resource  using [Goutte Laravel 4](https://github.com/everlaat/laravel4-goutte):

```
$client = Goutte::getNewClient();

//*
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://domain.mg/admin');

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'));

//*/

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://domain.mg/usergroup/list'); // Yields JSON Response

return dd($crawler);
```

It yields an output like so:

> object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler)#285 (4) {
>   ["uri":protected]=> string(36) "http://domain.mg/usergroup/list"
>   ["defaultNamespacePrefix":"Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler":private]=>
>   string(7) "default"
>   ["namespaces":"Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler":private]=>
>   array(0) { } ["storage":"SplObjectStorage":private]=> array(1) {
>   ["0000000075faaa10000000001af55ef8"]=> array(2) { ["obj"]=>
>   object(DOMElement)#241 (17) { ["tagName"]=> string(4) "html"
>   ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(4) "html"
>   ["nodeValue"]=> string(438) "[{"id":1,"group_name":"Compte
>   principal","group_desc":"Administrateur","group_level":9},{"id":2,"group_name":"Profil
>   pour les
>   comptables","group_desc":"Comptables","group_level":2},{"id":3,"group_name":"Validateur
>   d'op\u00e9ration","group_desc":"Superviseur","group_level":9},{"id":18,"group_name":"No
>   Comment","group_desc":"Autres
>   employ\u00e9s","group_level":6},{"id":41,"group_name":"Invit\u00e9","group_desc":"Guest","group_level":2}]"
>   ["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value
>   omitted)" ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
>   ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=>
>   string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> string(22)
>   "(object value omitted)" ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value
>   omitted)" ["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
>   ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=>
>   string(4) "html" ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(438)
>   "[{"id":1,"group_name":"Compte
>   principal","group_desc":"Administrateur","group_level":9},{"id":2,"group_name":"Profil
>   pour les
>   comptables","group_desc":"Comptables","group_level":2},{"id":3,"group_name":"Validateur
>   d'op\u00e9ration","group_desc":"Superviseur","group_level":9},{"id":18,"group_name":"No
>   Comment","group_desc":"Autres
>   employ\u00e9s","group_level":6},{"id":41,"group_name":"Invit\u00e9","group_desc":"Guest","group_level":2}]"
>   } ["inf"]=> NULL } } }

I stumbled at extracting/converting the internal representation of the JSON within `$crawler` object. How could that be done?

Comment: What you wanting to do with the JSON output exactly?

Comment: I want to pump remote data (static) into a local mirror database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delving into Class [Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_html) documentation, I found

```
public string html()

    Returns the first node of the list as HTML.

    Return Value

    string  The node html
```

which works as I expected.

Turning `return dd($crawler)` into `return ($crawler->html())` yields:

> [{"id":1,"group_name":"Compte
>   principal","group_desc":"Administrateur","group_level":9},{"id":2,"group_name":"Profil
>   pour les
>   comptables","group_desc":"Comptables","group_level":2},{"id":3,"group_name":"Validateur
>   d'op\u00e9ration","group_desc":"Superviseur","group_level":9},{"id":18,"group_name":"No
>   Comment","group_desc":"Autres
>   employ\u00e9s","group_level":6},{"id":41,"group_name":"Invit\u00e9","group_desc":"Guest","group_level":2}]

### Conclusion

Goutte managed very well the complex (Laravel | crsf mechanism) Login process but I dislike striping JSON string using `html()`.

Using `return ($crawler->text())` getting at the same outcome is more "neutral" my opinion to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure clear on what you are wanting to do with the JSON exactly, but its fairly simple to convert a JSON string to arrays:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Comment: That's plain PHP. Being not comfortable with [tag:goutte], I'm seeking the idiomatic way to retrieve at least the JSON string scattered within the $crawler object.

Comment: If you are able to retrieve the JSON string from the object, why not use `json_decode`? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: The stumbling block: How to retrieve the JSON string/JSON from the `$crawler` object? :-(

Comment: Goutte is using [CssSelector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) and [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) under the hood. I'm now delving into those Symfony component.

Comment: Oh, so you can't even get a JSON string from the object, okay.

Comment: Blame it on me (an enthusiast from the native language realm, not very comfortable with CSS and DOM): Goutte is very powerfull!